# Why is my BIOS version in 'msinfo32' entirely different from my real BIOS?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, gpu

I recently tried to install a GPU in my PC and found that my motherboard is no longer responding and ended up in a no signal stage (sometimes there occurs random restarts). After checking my bios I found that it is too old(where I don't see any options to switch between internal GPU or PCI-E slots)

So i decided to update my BIOS and for that I headed straight towards my system information via `msinfo32`, where I found my BIOS version was **Acer PO1-AO** & **SMBIOS version-2.7** (20/7/2012). But I couldn't find a model name as it was written Aspire series!(image attached)

Next I opened up the BIOS where I saw entirely different things. In my bios it was written *Aptio setup utility - 2011 American Megatrends. Inc* with a BIOS **version 2.14.1219**, whereas my Motherboard is ECS H61H2-M2(image attached).

Is this supposed to be happening? How can I update my BIOS? Please help.

Thank you.

[image: BIOS][image: System Info]

Comment: 1) Is your computer actually an Acer model? 2) Aptio is the name of the motherboard firmware, written by a company called [American Megatrends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Megatrends).

Comment: Yes. I brought a Veriton version of Acer. But someday my mobo got damaged. After a service. The model has turned to Aspire. Can u tell me how to update my BIOS

Comment: On the Acer website, there is a "Drivers and Manuals" section. Somewhere on that page is a link to their serial number detection utility. If you run that to get the serial number, you should then be able to find your way to the BIOS for that motherboard, and it should have instructions with it.

Comment: I already did the same. But my Serial number is just 18 digits and all they say is product not found!

Comment: I am reluctant to suggest using the ECS BIOS because there is a possibility that the motherboard will be broken by it. Oh, and the [SMBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) is not the same thing as the BIOS, so you would expect the version numbers to be different.

Comment: What is the make and model of the graphics card? Do you *know* that it works?

Comment: Its an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 710!!!

Comment: The motherboard should work with PCIe graphics with any version of its BIOS. You will need to find the CLR_CMOS jumper on the motherboard before the next step, in case you need to reset the BIOS. Make sure the graphics card is seated properly (there is a small clip on the socket). Then change the "Internal Graphics" setting to "Disabled", save the settings and reboot. Move the monitor lead onto the graphics card.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, switch it off, disconnect the monitor lead, remove the grahics card, attach the monitor lead to the motherboard display connector, and see if you get a picture when you switch it on. If not, switch it off, move the CLR_BIOS jumper to the other position, wait 2 minutes, move the CLR_BIOS jumper back to its original position. The BIOS will have been reset and the internal graphics setting will be back to "Enabled".

Comment: I think disabling Integrated Graphics is in BIOS, But after installing GPU the CPU doesn't even show the BIOS. If I connect the Monitor lead(here VGA) to the GPU, I can see the brand logo "acer" after which the PC is prompted to restart! whereas if I connect it to the mobo, the system won't restart but would end up in a no signal stage(Monitor led blink)

Comment: When the BIOS seems to be misbehaving, you should note down all the settings which are not the defaults (for example some disk drive settings might have been changed, and there may be other changes). Then load the BIOS defaults (press F3 according to the screen shot in the question) and see if it works.

Comment: But after installing GPU. I can't see the BIOS!! only then I can see if there's any change. Right!

Comment: Load the BIOS Optimized Defaults with the card not installed. Switch off, wait 30 seconds for the PSU to be completely discharged, install the card. It is possible that the PCIe socket has some dirt in it, or the graphics card is faulty.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Then it seems that the graphics card is faulty.

Comment: No it worked on my cousin's PC

Comment: I think its the problem with my PSU. the GPU need 300W. I only got a PSU with 300W

Comment: Ah, yes, that *could* be a problem. Although I would expect a PSU in an Acer computer to meet its specification. Is there anything that can be disconnected temporarily to reduce the power draw, for example a DVD drive or LED lighting? If you decide to get a higher power PSU, do make sure to get one from a reputable brand, because the ones that look like a bargain often cannot safely supply the power they say they can. Oh, and check the physical size in case it needs to be quite short.

Comment: That's true!! Maybe I can disconnect some wires(especially DVD coz I don't use it)

Comment: Do you think its with the VGA?

Comment: Would it be possible to test it in your cousin's PC again?

Comment: Yeah! sure, I can try it!. He used a DVI cable. That is why I asked about the thing with the DVI.